# Assigning values to variable on the fly in WHILE loop condition

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, conditional-statements

I've this piece of code

```
$limit = 100;
$offset = 0;

while (array() === ($contactIdList = $this->getData($limit, $offset))) {
    $count = count($contactIdList);
    //using $count and $contactIdList for doing some logging stuff  
    $offset += $limit;
}
```

> $this->getData($offset)
>   //Returns array of results from a query in which we set $limit, $offset so when all the results are been fetched it returns empty array and this while conditions end.

My question is i'm assigning array results in `$contactIdList` in while condition to save one line `$contactIdList = $this->getData($limit, $offset)` inside while condition. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1):

This looks fine for me. Just one suggestion, you can use empty() if you are using PHP 5.5.0 and later to check for empty array

```
$limit = 100;
$offset = 0;

while(!empty($contactIdList = $this->getData($limit, $offset))) {
    $count = count($contactIdList);
    //using $count and $contactIdList for doing some logging stuff  
    $offset += $limit;
}
```

Comment: Expressions in `empty()` are not allowed.

Comment: It supports expression from PHP 5.5.0

Comment: Yes, but sadly most still have a lower PHP version than 5.5.

Comment: ya,that's true. Thanks, i'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do as -

```
while ($contactIdList = $this->getData($limit, $offset)) {
```